# How to fill an Eigen Vector with another Eigen Vector?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a defined Eigen `vector1` and an undefined Eigen `vector2`, how do i fill `vector2` with values of `vector1` and subsequent data (doubles) like:

```
Eigen::RowVectorXd vector1 = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(1);
Eigen::RowVectorXd vector2;
vector2 << vector1, 2.0, 3.4 // Gives AssertionError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<<` operator can only be used to fill an Eigen::Vector if its size corresponds to that of the supplied data.
You could either declare the vector with the correct dimension

```
Eigen::RowVectorXd vector2(vector1.size() + 2);
```

or resize it

```
vector2.resize(vector1.size() + 2);
```

before using the `<<` operator to fill in the values.

Comment: Thanks, i tried, resizing first like `vector2.resize(vector1.size())` then `vector2 << vector1`. Followed by  `vector2.resize(vector1.size() + 1)` then filling it with `vector2 << 2.0`. But this spits out another `AssertionError`, saying `"Too few coefficients passed to comma initializer (operator<<)"`

Comment: I believe that in your failed attempt you wanted to write `vector2 << vector1, 2.0;` and not `vector2 << 2.0`. Else the size of vector2 would need to be 1.

Comment: Note that Eigen does not have a "push_back" functionality. The right hand side of  `<<` must contain the entire data of the vector.

Comment: Oh I see, if i were to resize `vector2` to `vector2.resize(vector1.size() + 1)` after filling `vector2 << vector1` would the elements of `vector1` be gone in `vector2`?

Comment: Yes, I would assume that this data would be lost. The developers of Eigen might give more precise information on the specific behavior of `resize()`, but I would always consider an Eigen vector to be uninitialized after a `resize()` operation.